# How to not select rows that does not exists in other table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, notin

I want to not select rows where record does not exists in other table

I expect to not select 3 rows where it does not exists on LOCATION table but exist in CYCLE_COUNT_REQUEST

code below

[image]

Comment: can you show us what have you tried ?

Comment: [Inner Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017) ?

Comment: hi, updated my question with code i used

Comment: Please paste the code and don't post screenshots!

Comment: i cant seem to post the code, site is showing errors so i posted the screenshot

Comment: If you get an error posting code (which error?) please report this at [meta]

Comment: Change your LEFT OUTER JOIN on Location to an INNER JOIN.  That way you only get matching records.

Answer (score 0):

use `NOT EXISTS`

```
select *
from CYCLE_COUNT_REQUEST
where not exists (select 1 
                  from LOCATION  )
```

Or `NOT IN`:

```
 select *
    from CYCLE_COUNT_REQUEST
    where NOT IN(select 1 
                      from LOCATION  )
```