# MySQL, select non-matching reference or reference does not exist in other table

Tags: mysql

MySQL, select non-matching reference or reference does not exist in other table.

For example.

```
table: category
category_id,    category_name
1               XYZ_1
2               XYZ_2
3               XYZ_3
4               XYZ_4
5               XYZ_5
6               XYZ_6


table: type
type_id,    type_name
1           A
2           B
3           C
4           D


table: type_match
match_Id,   type_id category_id
1           2       1
2           3       1
3           4       1
4           1       1
5           2       2
6           3       2
7           2       3       
8           4       3
9           2       4
```

I need category_id where type_id is not 3 or category_id does not exist in type_match table: 
expected result:

```
category_id
3  // category_id exist in type_match table but not matching type_id = 3
4  // category_id exist in type_match table but not matching type_id = 3
5  // category_id does not exist in type_match table
6  // category_id does not exist in type_match table
```

Please help.

I tried following answer but not succeed.

[How to not select rows that does not exists in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842912/how-to-not-select-rows-that-does-not-exists-in-other-table)

Comment: [Cross-posting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267888/mysql-get-rows-for-non-matching-reference-or-reference-does-not-exist-in-other)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` query here, checking that there is no row in `type_match` that has a given `category_id` and a `type_id` of 3:

```
SELECT *
FROM category c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM type_match t
                  WHERE t.category_id = c.category_id 
                    AND t.type_id = 3
                  )
```

Output:

```
category_id     category_name
3               XYZ_3
4               XYZ_4
5               XYZ_5
6               XYZ_6
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6QYR7rP3ogLvaoYPa99589/0)

Answer (score -1):

I would probably just use exists logic here:

```
SELECT c.category_id, c.category_name
FROM category c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM type_match t
                  WHERE t.type_id = t.category_id AND t.category_id = c.category_id);
```

[image: screen capture of demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: But this record does not change the relation of the `category = 4` record to OP's conditions... Where do you take into account the condition "where type_id is not 3"?

Comment: I think we are interpreting the question differently.  I am assuming that `3` is just an example of a category which fails the requirements.  The reason it fails, is not that it is 3, but rather that it doesn't have a matching type.

Comment: Citate: `4  // category_id exist in type_match table but not matching type_id = 3` Category id = 4, but type_id = 3 is used for checking nevertheless. *I am assuming that 3 is just an example* Agreed, but this is the same example condition for all records. Maybe OP will change it to another value, but again for all records.